# Converting co-ordinates to grid matrix

Tags: java, image, image-processing, coordinates

In my application, I would need to convert a set of  co-ordinates into a grid of 1's and 0's. It is explained below with examples:

**Input**: The region of interest on an image represented as x-axis and y-axis co-ordinates

*For eg:*

**x-coordinates**: 0;0.8;0.8;0
 and **y-coordinates**: 0;0;1;1

Sample image

[image]

**Output**: Matrix of 1's and 0's . Area selected in the input should be represented as a 1 and others as 0

For eg (width = 5 and height = 5)

Should give the output: 1111011110111101111011110

*Which can be represented as below:*

### | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

### | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

### | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

### | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

### | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Note: The width and height should be configurable, it can go upto 1080 * 720.

Is there any library I could make use of? Unable to find any good guide online (yet) . Any suggestions on how to go about it?

I have tried my best to explain with examples, but please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: You should provide some insights on what you've already done and tried. Generally a possible approach would be to discretize the coordinates on your image into categories according to how "exact" your grid should look like. Like this you can map each coordinate into a grid cell. Eg. if you want an 8x8 grid, each coordinate's cell is (x_coord/8,y_coord/8). And then you can set the 0/1 in each cell of your (8x8) matrix depending on the coordinate values it represents.

Comment: you don't need any library for that. that's simple maths

Comment: Honestly speaking, I haven't been able to make a start :-( . Maybe my maths is not good enough, I am not able to understand the solution given above too. Note that these lines can be 3,4,5 and can be a triangle, square, polygon.. And the space inside should be considered as area of interest (zeros) . I do not understand the part where we map these coordinates to a grid..